# Web3.js not giving accounts back using geth node

Tags: ethereum, web3js, go-ethereum

I am using a Go-Ethereum node with flags

```
geth --networkid '49' --datadir 'E:\Dir' --rpc --rpcapi 'web3, net, personal, admin, eth' --rpccorsdomain '*' console
```

I am trying to get Accounts using Web3.js. Whenever I try to request accounts using..

> web3.eth.accounts[0]

or

> web3.eth.getAccounts(accounts => console.log(accounts));

i get an error and hence when  print the whole Web3 response there isnt any accounts there and it shows the following error..

> [Exception: Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node
> http://localhost:8545. at Object.InvalidConnection
> (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/web3/dist/web3.js:3137:16) at
> HttpProvider.send
> (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/web3/dist/web3.js:4350:18) at
> RequestManager.send
> (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/web3/dist/web3.js:6357:32) at
> Eth.get [as accounts]
> (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/web3/dist/web3.js:6260:62) at
> Eth.remoteFunction (:2:14)]

and when i try  my index.html page without an HTPP-SERVER running the error is

> Failed to load http://localhost:8545/: Response to preflight request
> doesn't pass access control check: The value of the
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which
> must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
> Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of
> requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the
> withCredentials attribute. HttpProvider.send @ web3.js:4348
>
> Uncaught Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node
> http://localhost:8545.
> at Object.InvalidConnection (web3.js:3137)
> at HttpProvider.send (web3.js:4350)
> at RequestManager.send (web3.js:6357)
> at Eth.get [as accounts] (web3.js:6260)
> at index.html:50

I don't know where the problem lies. Is there any problem related to flags in the node or some method within JavaScript?

Comment: Maybe a silly question: are geth and your javascript running on the same host machine? At first glance it looks like a basic connection failure. Also, any errors in your geth logs?

Comment: Yeah, it is running on the same machine, i am using the latest beta version and having problem in that version otherwise it is running fine on older versions of web3.js

Comment: another solution is to add this line of code  var options = {timeout: 20000,headers: [{name: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', value: '*'}]}; with http provider  like             web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("", options));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue and I fixed it after I run the following command.

`npm install web3@0.20.6 --save`

check this [link](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1826)